# How do I calculate driving distance to Amarillo, TX from all Texas cities using zipcode data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis

I have a dataset that contains the zipcode of all cities in Texas.

I want to find the distance of all these cities in Texas to ...Amarillo,TX

Example:

Borger, TX------Amarillo,TX
Pampa,TX--------Amarillo,TX
San Angelo,TX---Amarillo,TX
.
.
.
I have about 1700 cities in TX and their zip code, I need their distances to Amarillo, TX. Please let me know a way to do this easily.

Comment: crow-flies? network distance?

Comment: Dan....all roads lead to Rome (Amarillo, TX). Distance like driving distance.

Comment: You will need the network analyst extension then for use within the Arc* line of products

Comment: I answered but it was for "as the crow flies" Euclidean distance. For driving distance if you do not have network analyst then you may be better off with using PostGIS' pgRouting: http://pgrouting.org/

Comment: Are you measuring from the zip code/city centroid, or from the border?

Comment: @Erica, dosent matter, centroid or border something approximate.

Comment: @DanPatterson Conor ...this is just a simple distance between two cities , why all this complicated..ArcViewGis, pgRouting...15 different tools..just unwanted complications

Comment: If you want to calculate the distance along roads (driving distance), you need to have road network data and the additional tools. If you want straight-line distance (also called Euclidean distance, or as the crow flies distance), it is a much simpler process. Conor and Dan are just trying to make sure you get a solution that matches your specific needs.

Comment: Because driving distance entails the use of roads, hence, a network...straight line distance is much easier, but leave the vehicle at home

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of Generate Near Table? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001n000000

Comment: @Erica, yes I agree. I am not blaming Dan or Connor, I am just saying why this information is not available publicly and why hiding all this under 15 different softwares and charge $ for this

Comment: @AdamThom, yes something similar, the IN_FID column will have all the city zip codes and NEAR_FID will be (Amarillo, TX).

Comment: The data to do what you want is available for free and publicly, but it takes effort to use on your part. To get *driving* distances, you need roads to measure along. Data collection costs money, but you can get a road network for free (TIGER data, maybe even from Texas or another source). Your cities/zips have to be made into points. Then it's a routing problem of point a to b *along the network*. ArcGIS requires an extra extension to do this. QGIS (among others) has free alternatives that can do the same thing but might not be as streamlined. You can have easy, cheap, or accurate. Pick two.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to revise it with the clarifications that have been sought via comments, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the appropriate licence (ArcGIS Advanced), using the Generate Near Table would work fine for what you are looking for. It is fairly simple to use following the instructions on the ArcGIS Resource page.

However, it appears as though you may not be too familiar with GIS software, so you may wish to simplify your output by adding the city layer two times to the table of contents and applying a definition query on one that is something like "Name" = 'Amarillo', and a definition query on the other that is "Name" <> 'Amarillo'. To put a definition query on  your feature, right click on it, click on the Definition Query tab, and use the query builder. This should generate one table of all the distances from the city to Amarillo.

If, like me, you do not have access to ArcGIS Advanced, QGIS (which is free) has the same function under Vector --> Analysis Tools --> Distance Matrix.

Comment: This will only generate straight line, as the crow flies, Euclidean, (insert alternative adjective here) distances. Asker has stated they want *driving* distances, which **requires** a network and network analysis.

Comment: Thanks Adam, Chris, Erica...I find someone who has license to a PCMiller software which I am told will give me the distance. So hopeful I will get this data and proceed quickly to tackle a bigger problem